# Jquery append method add more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons and each button has own value. I click button it shows normally %40 but when i click other button it shows %40%80 instead of %80.

```
$("#cat1").click(function () {
    $(".yuzde").append(" ");
    $(".neler-biliyorum-grafikhover").css("width", "40%");
    $(".yuzde").append("%40");
});
$("#cat2").click(function () {
    $(".yuzde").append(" ");
    $(".neler-biliyorum-grafikhover").css("width", "40%");
    $(".yuzde").append("%80");
});
```

Html is

```
<div class="neler-biliyorum-grafik">
    <div class="neler-biliyorum-grafikhover">
       <div class="yuzde"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `html()`, instead of `append()`

Comment: @AmitSoni Might replace the existing content, if available

Comment: You didn't added `#cat1` and `#cat2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `append` use `html()` if you want to replace the exisint HTML and not add to it. Append will appent to existing part.

```
$("#cat1").click(function () {
    $(".neler-biliyorum-grafikhover").css("width", "40%");
    $(".yuzde").html("%40");
});
$("#cat2").click(function () {
    $(".neler-biliyorum-grafikhover").css("width", "40%");
    $(".yuzde").html("%80");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> .append()
>
> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

So, You need to use `innerHTML` or `html` instead of `append`

```
      $("#cat1").click(function () {
           $(".yuzde")[0].innerHTML=" ";
           $(".neler-biliyorum-grafikhover").css("width", "40%");
           $(".yuzde").html("%40");
      });
      $("#cat2").click(function () {
           $(".yuzde").html(" ");
           $(".neler-biliyorum-grafikhover").css("width", "40%");
           $(".yuzde")[0].innerHTML="%80";
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** to clear previous data

```js
var $ele = $(".neler-biliyorum-grafikhover"),
  $show = $(".yuzde");
$("#cat1").click(function() {
  $ele.css("width", "40%");
  $show.html("%40");
});
$("#cat2").click(function() {
  $ele.css("width", "80%");
  $show.html("%80");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="neler-biliyorum-grafik">
  <div class="neler-biliyorum-grafikhover">
    <div class="yuzde"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="cat1">a</button>
<button id="cat2">b</button>
```